# Problems compiling paper on arxiv

Tags: natbib, arxiv

I am having trouble compiling a paper on the arXiv. I use sharelatex and everything runs fine with the citations in my paper using the MNRAS style sheets. However, when I upload my source code to the arXiv, I get a paper with missing citations. I would be happy if someone could help me with this. I show some of my arXiv log file here which should contain sufficient information to try to solve the problem:

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `becker14' on page 11 undefined on input line
347.

<figs/phi_90_extended_contour.pdf, id=360, 349.41608pt x 283.50626pt>
<use figs/phi_90_extended_contour.pdf>
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [11]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `nellis97' on page 12 undefined on input line
381.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `becker14' on page 12 undefined on input line
381.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `militzer13' on page 12 undefined on input lin
e 381.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `salpeter73' on page 12 undefined on input lin
e 381.


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [12 <./fig
s/iron_phi60_plots.pdf>]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `korycansky20' on page 13 undefined on input l
ine 385.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `artemieva01' on page 13 undefined on input li
ne 388.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `korycansky05' on page 13 undefined on input l
ine 388.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pond12' on page 13 undefined on input line 39
2.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pond12' on page 13 undefined on input line 39
2.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `korycansky06' on page 13 undefined on input l
ine 392.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pond12' on page 13 undefined on input line 39
2.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pond12' on page 13 undefined on input line 39
3.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pond12' on page 13 undefined on input line 39
3.

<figs/Pond_comp.pdf, id=400, 430.56712pt x 386.41872pt>
<use figs/Pond_comp.pdf>

Package natbib Warning: Citation `pond12' on page 13 undefined on input line 39
7.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pond12' on page 13 undefined on input line 39
7.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `mordasini15' on page 13 undefined on input li
ne 401.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `mordasini15' on page 13 undefined on input li
ne 401.

[13 <./figs/phi_90_extended_contour.pdf> <./figs/Pond_comp.pdf>]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `podolak88' on page 14 undefined on input line
403.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `podolak88' on page 14 undefined on input line
403.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `bodenheimer86' on page 14 undefined on input
line 403.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `salpeter73' on page 14 undefined on input lin
e 411.

(./ms_0.bbl
Underfull \hbox (badness 5893) in paragraph at lines 1--16
[]\T1/txr/m/n/9 @ARTICLEwinn15, au-thor = Winn, J. N. and Fab-

Underfull \hbox (badness 2213) in paragraph at lines 1--16
\T1/txr/m/n/9 rycky, D. C., ti-tle = "The Oc-cur-rence and Ar-chi-tec-ture of

Underfull \hbox (badness 2359) in paragraph at lines 1--16
\T1/txr/m/n/9 Ex-o-plan-e-tary Sys-tems", jour-nal = ARA&A, archivePre-fix =

Underfull \hbox (badness 2547) in paragraph at lines 1--16
\T1/txr/m/n/9 "arXiv", eprint = 1410.4199, pri-ma-ryClass = "astro-ph.EP",

Underfull \hbox (badness 2478) in paragraph at lines 1--16
\T1/txr/m/n/9 year = 2015, month = aug, vol-ume = 53, pages = 409-

Underfull \hbox (badness 4981) in paragraph at lines 1--16
\T1/txr/m/n/9 447, doi = 10.1146/annurev-astro-082214-122246, adsurl =

Underfull \hbox (badness 2573) in paragraph at lines 20--33
\T1/txr/m/n/9 son, H. and Fort-ney, J. J. and Bar-man, T., ti-tle = "Ex-o-

Underfull \hbox (badness 4156) in paragraph at lines 20--33
\T1/txr/m/n/9 archivePre-fix = "arXiv", eprint = 1402.1169, pri-ma-ryClass

Underfull \hbox (badness 2293) in paragraph at lines 20--33
\T1/txr/m/n/9 = "astro-ph.EP", year = 2014, pages = 739-762, adsurl =

Underfull \hbox (badness 3250) in paragraph at lines 36--54
[]\T1/txr/m/n/9 @ARTICLEmadhu14c, au-thor = Mad-husud-han, N. and

Underfull \hbox (badness 3302) in paragraph at lines 36--54
\T1/txr/m/n/9 Crouzet, N. and Mc-Cul-lough, P. R. and Dem-ing, D. and

Underfull \hbox (badness 2735) in paragraph at lines 36--54
\T1/txr/m/n/9 Hedges, C., ti-tle = "H$[]$O Abun-dances in the At-mo-spheres

Underfull \hbox (badness 7116) in paragraph at lines 36--54
\T1/txr/m/n/9 of Three Hot Jupiters", jour-nal = ApJ, archivePre-fix =

Underfull \hbox (badness 2547) in paragraph at lines 36--54
\T1/txr/m/n/9 "arXiv", eprint = 1407.6054, pri-ma-ryClass = "astro-ph.EP",

Underfull \hbox (badness 3568) in paragraph at lines 36--54
\T1/txr/m/n/9 key-words = plan-e-tary sys-tems, plan-ets and satel-lites: gen-

Underfull \hbox (badness 2409) in paragraph at lines 36--54
\T1/txr/m/n/9 eral , year = 2014, month = aug, vol-ume = 791, eid =

Underfull \hbox (badness 2073) in paragraph at lines 36--54
\T1/txr/m/n/9 L9, pages = L9, doi = 10.1088/2041-8205/791/1/L9, adsurl
[14]
Underfull \hbox (badness 3029) in paragraph at lines 55--72
[]\T1/txr/m/n/9 @ARTICLEmadhu14b, au-thor = Mad-husud-han, N. and

Underfull \hbox (badness 1342) in paragraph at lines 55--72
\T1/txr/m/n/9 Amin, M. A. and Kennedy, G. M., ti-tle = "To-ward Chem-

Underfull \hbox (badness 2384) in paragraph at lines 55--72
\T1/txr/m/n/9 i-cal Con-straints on Hot Jupiter Mi-gra-tion", jour-nal = ApJ,

Underfull \hbox (badness 5417) in paragraph at lines 77--95
[]\T1/txr/m/n/9 @ARTICLEmadhu11, au-thor = Mad-husud-han, N. and

Underfull \hbox (badness 5893) in paragraph at lines 77--95
\T1/txr/m/n/9 Mousis, O. and John-son, T. V. and Lu-nine, J. I., ti-tle

Underfull \hbox (badness 1424) in paragraph at lines 77--95
\T1/txr/m/n/9 = "Carbon-rich Gi-ant Plan-ets: At-mo-spheric Chem-istry, Ther-

Underfull \hbox (badness 2351) in paragraph at lines 77--95
\T1/txr/m/n/9 mal In-ver-sions, Spec-tra, and For-ma-tion Con-di-tions", jour-n
al

Underfull \hbox (badness 1253) in paragraph at lines 77--95
\T1/txr/m/n/9 = ApJ, archivePre-fix = "arXiv", eprint = 1109.3183, pri-ma-

Underfull \hbox (badness 2393) in paragraph at lines 77--95
\T1/txr/m/n/9 ets and satel-lites: gen-eral, plan-ets and satel-lites: in-di-vi
d-ual:

Underfull \hbox (badness 3657) in paragraph at lines 97--112
[]\T1/txr/m/n/9 @ARTICLEjura08, au-thor = Jura, M., ti-tle = "Pol-lu-

Underfull \hbox (badness 1997) in paragraph at lines 97--112
\T1/txr/m/n/9 tion of Sin-gle White Dwarfs by Ac-cre-tion of Many Small

Underfull \hbox (badness 5592) in paragraph at lines 97--112
\T1/txr/m/n/9 As-ter-oids", jour-nal = AJ, archivePre-fix = "arXiv", eprint

Underfull \hbox (badness 2261) in paragraph at lines 97--112
\T1/txr/m/n/9 = 0802.4075, key-words = plan-e-tary sys-tems, white dwarfs,

Underfull \hbox (badness 6978) in paragraph at lines 97--112
\T1/txr/m/n/9 year = 2008, month = may, vol-ume = 135, pages =

Underfull \hbox (badness 5862) in paragraph at lines 97--112
\T1/txr/m/n/9 1785-1792, doi = 10.1088/0004-6256/135/5/1785, adsurl =

Underfull \hbox (badness 2435) in paragraph at lines 146--159
[]\T1/txr/m/n/9 @ARTICLEmaclow94, au-thor = Mac Low, M.-M. and

Underfull \hbox (badness 1087) in paragraph at lines 161--174
\T1/txr/m/n/9 P. J. and Zahnle, K. J., ti-tle = "The 1908 Tun-guska ex-plo-

Underfull \hbox (badness 1577) in paragraph at lines 161--174
\T1/txr/m/n/9 ta-tion, Hy-per-ve-loc-ity Im-pact, Math-e-mat-i-cal Mod-els, EAR
TH,

Underfull \hbox (badness 1681) in paragraph at lines 161--174
\T1/txr/m/n/9 SIM-U-LA-TIONS, SIZE, AL-TI-TUDE, BERRINGER CRATER,

Underfull \hbox (badness 1062) in paragraph at lines 161--174
\T1/txr/m/n/9 ER-A-TION, AB-LA-TION, year = 1993, month = jan, vol-ume

Underfull \hbox (badness 2269) in paragraph at lines 161--174
\T1/txr/m/n/9 = 361, pages = 40-44, doi = 10.1038/361040a0, adsurl =

Underfull \vbox (badness 2326) has occurred while \output is active
Underfull \hbox (badness 1072) in paragraph at lines 176--189
\T1/txr/m/n/9 ter, I. and Brecht, S. H. and Dem-ing, D. and Mead-ows, V.

Underfull \hbox (badness 1418) in paragraph at lines 192--205
\T1/txr/m/n/9 Type I car-bona-ceous chon-drite", jour-nal = Geochim-ica Cos-

Underfull \hbox (badness 1210) in paragraph at lines 192--205
\T1/txr/m/n/9 mochim-ica Acta, year = 1967, month = oct, vol-ume = 31,

Underfull \hbox (badness 1102) in paragraph at lines 206--224
\T1/txr/m/n/9 W. and Fort-ney, J. J. and Net-tel-mann, N. and Sch�t-tler, M.

Underfull \hbox (badness 1314) in paragraph at lines 206--224
\T1/txr/m/n/9 ca-tions for the In-te-rior of Brown Dwarfs", jour-nal = ApJS,

Underfull \hbox (badness 2245) in paragraph at lines 225--243
[]\T1/txr/m/n/9 @ARTICLEnettelmann12, au-thor = Net-tel-mann, N. and

Underfull \hbox (badness 1205) in paragraph at lines 225--243
\T1/txr/m/n/9 Becker, A. and Holst, B. and Red-mer, R. , ti-tle = "Jupiter

Underfull \hbox (badness 7595) in paragraph at lines 225--243
\T1/txr/m/n/9 Mod-els with Im-proved Ab Ini-tio Hy-dro-gen Equa-tion of

Underfull \hbox (badness 1616) in paragraph at lines 225--243
\T1/txr/m/n/9 State (H-REOS.2)", jour-nal = ApJ, archivePre-fix = "arXiv",

Underfull \hbox (badness 1297) in paragraph at lines 225--243
\T1/txr/m/n/9 eprint = 1109.5644, pri-ma-ryClass = "astro-ph.EP", key-words

Underfull \hbox (badness 4193) in paragraph at lines 225--243
\T1/txr/m/n/9 year = 2012, month = may, vol-ume = 750, eid = 52,

Underfull \hbox (badness 4060) in paragraph at lines 225--243
\T1/txr/m/n/9 pages = 52, doi = 10.1088/0004-637X/750/1/52, adsurl =

Underfull \hbox (badness 1132) in paragraph at lines 260--273
\T1/txr/m/n/9 P. J. and Brook-shaw, L. and Sagan, C. , ti-tle = "Cometary

Underfull \hbox (badness 3965) in paragraph at lines 260--273
\T1/txr/m/n/9 De-liv-ery of Or-ganic Molecules to the Early Earth", jour-

Underfull \hbox (badness 1675) in paragraph at lines 260--273
\T1/txr/m/n/9 nal = Sci-ence, year = 1990, month = jul, vol-ume = 249,

Underfull \hbox (badness 1286) in paragraph at lines 260--273
\T1/txr/m/n/9 pages = 366-373, doi = 10.1126/sci-ence.11538074, adsurl =

Underfull \vbox (badness 3690) has occurred while \output is active [15]
Underfull \hbox (badness 2020) in paragraph at lines 286--296
\T1/txr/m/n/9 "Physics of me-te-oric phe-nom-ena", key-words = At-mo-spheric

Underfull \hbox (badness 1221) in paragraph at lines 286--296
\T1/txr/m/n/9 Physics, Earth At-mo-sphere, Me-te-orites, Me-te-oroids, Ab-la-ti
on,

Underfull \hbox (badness 1371) in paragraph at lines 286--296
\T1/txr/m/n/9 Lu-mi-nes-cence, Mass, Me-teor Trails, Shock Waves, Spec-trum

Underfull \hbox (badness 3471) in paragraph at lines 299--311
\T1/txr/m/n/9 jour-nal = Icarus, year = 2000, month = aug, vol-ume =

Underfull \hbox (badness 1910) in paragraph at lines 329--344
[]\T1/txr/m/n/9 @ARTICLEfrench12, au-thor = French, M. and Becker,

Underfull \hbox (badness 1783) in paragraph at lines 329--344
\T1/txr/m/n/9 nal = ApJS, key-words = con-duc-tion, dif-fu-sion, equa-tion of

Underfull \hbox (badness 1038) in paragraph at lines 329--344
\T1/txr/m/n/9 = 5, pages = 5, doi = 10.1088/0067-0049/202/1/5, adsurl =

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 347--358
\T1/txr/m/n/9 Mechanical The-ory of Ir-re-versible Pro-cesses. I", jour-

Underfull \hbox (badness 4181) in paragraph at lines 347--358
\T1/txr/m/n/9 nal = Jour-nal of the Phys-i-cal So-ci-ety of Japan, year =

Underfull \hbox (badness 1810) in paragraph at lines 347--358
\T1/txr/m/n/9 1957, month = jun, vol-ume = 12, pages = 570, adsurl =

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 347--358
\T1/txr/m/n/9 http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1957JPSJ...12..570K, ad-snote =

Underfull \hbox (badness 2351) in paragraph at lines 361--374
\T1/txr/m/n/9 TIONS, TWO-BODY PROB-LEM, TRA-JEC-TO-RIES, DRAG,

Underfull \hbox (badness 1107) in paragraph at lines 361--374
\T1/txr/m/n/9 COM-PAR-ISONS, year = 1988, month = jan, vol-ume = 73,

Underfull \vbox (badness 2326) has occurred while \output is active
Underfull \hbox (badness 7362) in paragraph at lines 376--386
[]\T1/txr/m/n/9 @ARTICLEpetrovic03, au-thor = Petro-vic, S. T. and

Underfull \hbox (badness 5147) in paragraph at lines 376--386
\T1/txr/m/n/9 Markovic, S. and Pavlovic, Z. A., jour-nal = Jour-nal of

Underfull \hbox (badness 4752) in paragraph at lines 376--386
\T1/txr/m/n/9 Ma-te-ri-als Sci-ence, year = 2003, vol-ume = 38, pages =

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 376--386
\T1/txr/m/n/9 3263-3268, doi = 10.1023/A:1025133904322, adsurl =

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 376--386
\T1/txr/m/n/9 http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2003JMatS..38.3263P, ad-snote

Underfull \hbox (badness 1721) in paragraph at lines 387--399
\T1/txr/m/n/9 lic hy-dro-gen at high pres-sures and tem-per-a-ture in Jupiter."
,

Underfull \hbox (badness 1540) in paragraph at lines 387--399
\T1/txr/m/n/9 - 1924, key-words = Jupiter: Chem-i-cal Com-po-si-tion, year =

Underfull \hbox (badness 1286) in paragraph at lines 401--413
\T1/txr/m/n/9 ume = 181, pages = L83, doi = 10.1086/181190, adsurl =

Underfull \hbox (badness 1237) in paragraph at lines 434--447
\T1/txr/m/n/9 Shu-valov, V. V., ti-tle = "Mo-tion of a frag-mented me-te-oroid

Underfull \hbox (badness 1337) in paragraph at lines 434--447
\T1/txr/m/n/9 key-words = Plan-e-tol-ogy: Solid Sur-face Plan-ets: Im-pact phe-


Underfull \vbox (badness 2326) has occurred while \output is active [16]
Underfull \hbox (badness 3260) in paragraph at lines 484--499
[]\T1/txr/m/n/9 @ARTICLEkorycansky06, au-thor = Ko-rycan-sky, D. G.

Underfull \hbox (badness 1917) in paragraph at lines 484--499
\T1/txr/m/n/9 and Har-ring-ton, J. and Dem-ing, D. and Kulick, M. E., ti-

Underfull \hbox (badness 2503) in paragraph at lines 484--499
\T1/txr/m/n/9 Three-dimensional Bolides", jour-nal = ApJ, eprint = astro-

Underfull \hbox (badness 6641) in paragraph at lines 484--499
\T1/txr/m/n/9 9), Hy-dro-dy-nam-ics, year = 2006, month = jul, vol-ume

Underfull \hbox (badness 5817) in paragraph at lines 484--499
\T1/txr/m/n/9 = 646, pages = 642-652, doi = 10.1086/504702, adsurl

Underfull \hbox (badness 1454) in paragraph at lines 501--513
[]\T1/txr/m/n/9 @INPROCEEDINGSkorycansky15, au-thor = Ko-rycan-sky,

Underfull \hbox (badness 1087) in paragraph at lines 501--513
\T1/txr/m/n/9 D. G., ti-tle = "Mod-el-ing the Chelyabinsk Im-pact, 2", book-

Underfull \hbox (badness 5403) in paragraph at lines 501--513
\T1/txr/m/n/9 ti-tle = Lu-nar and Plan-e-tary Sci-ence Con-fer-ence, year =

Underfull \hbox (badness 6284) in paragraph at lines 501--513
\T1/txr/m/n/9 2015, se-ries = Lu-nar and Plan-e-tary Sci-ence Con-fer-ence,

Underfull \hbox (badness 6708) in paragraph at lines 501--513
\T1/txr/m/n/9 vol-ume = 46, month = mar, pages = 1144, adsurl =

Underfull \hbox (badness 1454) in paragraph at lines 514--526
[]\T1/txr/m/n/9 @INPROCEEDINGSkorycansky14, au-thor = Ko-rycan-sky,

Underfull \hbox (badness 1939) in paragraph at lines 514--526
\T1/txr/m/n/9 pact", book-ti-tle = Lu-nar and Plan-e-tary Sci-ence Con-fer-ence
,

Underfull \hbox (badness 1194) in paragraph at lines 514--526
\T1/txr/m/n/9 year = 2014, se-ries = Lu-nar and Plan-e-tary Sci-ence Con-fer-

Underfull \hbox (badness 1189) in paragraph at lines 514--526
\T1/txr/m/n/9 ence, vol-ume = 45, month = mar, pages = 1269, adsurl =

Underfull \hbox (badness 1210) in paragraph at lines 540--560
\T1/txr/m/n/9 = http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013A26A...560A..55H, ad-snote

Underfull \hbox (badness 6792) in paragraph at lines 562--573
[]\T1/txr/m/n/9 @ARTICLErubinow61, au-thor = Ru-bi-now, S. I. and

Underfull \hbox (badness 6220) in paragraph at lines 562--573
\T1/txr/m/n/9 Keller, J. B., ti-tle = "The trans-verse force on a spin-

Underfull \hbox (badness 4403) in paragraph at lines 562--573
\T1/txr/m/n/9 ning sphere mov-ing in a vis-cous fluid", jour-nal = Jour-

Underfull \hbox (badness 1460) in paragraph at lines 562--573
\T1/txr/m/n/9 nal of Fluid Me-chan-ics, year = 1961, vol-ume = 11, pages

Underfull \hbox (badness 6526) in paragraph at lines 562--573
\T1/txr/m/n/9 = 447-459, doi = 10.1017/S0022112061000640, adsurl =

Underfull \hbox (badness 2057) in paragraph at lines 592--608
\T1/txr/m/n/9 e-tary sys-tems, year = 2015, month = oct, vol-ume = 453,

Underfull \hbox (badness 1831) in paragraph at lines 592--608
\T1/txr/m/n/9 pages = 1779-1792, doi = 10.1093/mn-ras/stv1712, adsurl =

Underfull \vbox (badness 1558) has occurred while \output is active
Underfull \hbox (badness 3713) in paragraph at lines 609--627
[]\T1/txr/m/n/9 @ARTICLEline12, au-thor = Line, M. R. and Zhang,

Underfull \hbox (badness 1472) in paragraph at lines 609--627
\T1/txr/m/n/9 X. and Va-sisht, G. and Na-traj, V. and Chen, P. and Yung,

Underfull \hbox (badness 3209) in paragraph at lines 609--627
\T1/txr/m/n/9 Y. L., ti-tle = "In-for-ma-tion Con-tent of Ex-o-plan-e-tary Tran
-

Underfull \hbox (badness 1142) in paragraph at lines 609--627
\T1/txr/m/n/9 spheres, plan-ets and satel-lites: in-di-vid-ual: HD189733b, ra-d
ia-

Underfull \hbox (badness 1168) in paragraph at lines 650--663
\T1/txr/m/n/9 Up-per Lim-its on the Carbon-to-Oxygen Ra-tios of Eight Hot

Underfull \hbox (badness 1371) in paragraph at lines 665--685
\T1/txr/m/n/9 adsurl = http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015ApJ...814...66K, ad-

Underfull \hbox (badness 3590) in paragraph at lines 688--705
[]\T1/txr/m/n/9 @ARTICLEmadhu12, au-thor = Mad-husud-han, N., ti-tle

Underfull \hbox (badness 1502) in paragraph at lines 688--705
\T1/txr/m/n/9 = "C/O Ra-tio as a Di-men-sion for Char-ac-ter-iz-ing Ex-o-plan-e
-

Underfull \hbox (badness 1997) in paragraph at lines 688--705
\T1/txr/m/n/9 tary At-mo-spheres", jour-nal = ApJ, archivePre-fix = "arXiv",

Underfull \hbox (badness 1297) in paragraph at lines 688--705
\T1/txr/m/n/9 eprint = 1209.2412, pri-ma-ryClass = "astro-ph.EP", key-words

Underfull \hbox (badness 6364) in paragraph at lines 688--705
\T1/txr/m/n/9 ets and satel-lites: gen-eral, plan-ets and satel-lites: in-di-vi
d-

Underfull \hbox (badness 5217) in paragraph at lines 688--705
\T1/txr/m/n/9 year = 2012, month = oct, vol-ume = 758, eid = 36,

Underfull \hbox (badness 4060) in paragraph at lines 688--705
\T1/txr/m/n/9 pages = 36, doi = 10.1088/0004-637X/758/1/36, adsurl =

Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [17]
Underfull \hbox (badness 4582) in paragraph at lines 747--764
\T1/txr/m/n/9 lines on C/O in Plan-e-tary At-mo-spheres", jour-nal = ApJ,

Underfull \hbox (badness 3872) in paragraph at lines 767--784
\T1/txr/m/n/9 adsurl = http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014Life....4..142H, ad-

Underfull \hbox (badness 2556) in paragraph at lines 819--832
\T1/txr/m/n/9 pages = 121-136, doi = 10.1007/s11214-005-1951-5, adsurl

Underfull \vbox (badness 2326) has occurred while \output is active
Underfull \hbox (badness 1270) in paragraph at lines 833--844
[]\T1/txr/m/n/9 @ARTICLEpapaloizou07, au-thor = Pa-paloizou, J. C. B.

Underfull \hbox (badness 2837) in paragraph at lines 833--844
\T1/txr/m/n/9 mow-icz, P., ti-tle = "Disk-Planet In-ter-ac-tions Dur-ing Planet


Underfull \hbox (badness 4024) in paragraph at lines 833--844
\T1/txr/m/n/9 For-ma-tion", jour-nal = Pro-to-stars and Plan-ets V, eprint =

Underfull \hbox (badness 1859) in paragraph at lines 833--844
\T1/txr/m/n/9 astro-ph/0603196, year = 2007, pages = 655-668, adsurl =

Underfull \hbox (badness 5787) in paragraph at lines 885--900
\T1/txr/m/n/9 adsurl = http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2000MNRAS.318...18N,

Underfull \hbox (badness 5417) in paragraph at lines 902--917
[]\T1/txr/m/n/9 @ARTICLEmadhu16, au-thor = Mad-husud-han, N. and

Underfull \hbox (badness 2512) in paragraph at lines 902--917
\T1/txr/m/n/9 Ag�n-dez, M. and Moses, J. I. and Hu, Y., ti-tle = "Ex-o-

Underfull \hbox (badness 1448) in paragraph at lines 902--917
\T1/txr/m/n/9 plan-e-tary At-mo-spheres and Chem-istry, For-ma-tion Con-di-tion
s,

Underfull \hbox (badness 5771) in paragraph at lines 902--917
\T1/txr/m/n/9 and Hab-it-abil-ity", jour-nal = Space Sci. Rev., archivePre-

Underfull \hbox (badness 1609) in paragraph at lines 902--917
\T1/txr/m/n/9 fix = "arXiv", eprint = 1604.06092, pri-ma-ryClass = "astro-

Underfull \hbox (badness 3199) in paragraph at lines 902--917
\T1/txr/m/n/9 mo-spheric chem-istry, Planet for-ma-tion, Hab-it-abil-ity, year
=

Underfull \hbox (badness 1297) in paragraph at lines 921--937
[]\T1/txr/m/n/9 @ARTICLEhelled09, au-thor = Helled, R. and Schu-bert,

Underfull \hbox (badness 1270) in paragraph at lines 921--937
\T1/txr/m/n/9 to-planet as a Func-tion of Or-bital Lo-ca-tion", jour-nal = ApJ,


Underfull \hbox (badness 4156) in paragraph at lines 921--937
\T1/txr/m/n/9 archivePre-fix = "arXiv", eprint = 0903.1997, pri-ma-ryClass

Underfull \hbox (badness 2150) in paragraph at lines 921--937
\T1/txr/m/n/9 = "astro-ph.EP", key-words = plan-e-tary sys-tems: pro-to-plan-e-


Underfull \hbox (badness 2142) in paragraph at lines 921--937
\T1/txr/m/n/9 ma-tion, year = 2009, month = jun, vol-ume = 697, pages

Underfull \hbox (badness 4621) in paragraph at lines 921--937
\T1/txr/m/n/9 = 1256-1262, doi = 10.1088/0004-637X/697/2/1256, adsurl

Underfull \vbox (badness 3690) has occurred while \output is active [18]
Underfull \hbox (badness 1014) in paragraph at lines 938--951
\T1/txr/m/n/9 me-te-oroids in Earth's at-mo-sphere: The-o-ret-i-cal mod-els.",
jour-

Underfull \hbox (badness 2608) in paragraph at lines 938--951
\T1/txr/m/n/9 nal = Icarus, year = 1995, month = jul, vol-ume = 116,

Underfull \hbox (badness 4403) in paragraph at lines 938--951
\T1/txr/m/n/9 pages = 131-153, doi = 10.1006/icar.1995.1116, adsurl =
) <figs/1000bar_contour_plots.pdf, id=461, 506.35643pt x 386.41872pt>
<use figs/1000bar_contour_plots.pdf>
<figs/ice_1000bar_contour_plots.pdf, id=462, 507.10075pt x 386.41872pt>
<use figs/ice_1000bar_contour_plots.pdf>
<figs/10Mbar_contour_plots.pdf, id=463, 506.5518pt x 385.26242pt>
<use figs/10Mbar_contour_plots.pdf>
<figs/core_ie_boundary_contour_plots.pdf, id=464, 507.08679pt x 385.84058pt>
<use figs/core_ie_boundary_contour_plots.pdf>

Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.

[19]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [20 <./fig
s/1000bar_contour_plots.pdf> <./figs/ice_1000bar_contour_plots.pdf>]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [21 <./fig
s/10Mbar_contour_plots.pdf> <./figs/core_ie_boundary_contour_plots.pdf>]
(./ms_0.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)pdfTeX warning (dest): name
{Hfootnote.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

{/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}</texlive/2011/texmf-dist
/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi12.pfb></texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type
1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb></texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/am
sfonts/cm/cmsy8.pfb></texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbo
ls/msam10.pfb></texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msb
m10.pfb></texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/rsfs/rsfs10.pfb></texlive/
2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/txfonts/rtxb.pfb></texlive/2011/texmf-dist/f
onts/type1/public/txfonts/rtxbmi.pfb></texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/publ
ic/txfonts/rtxi.pfb></texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/txfonts/rtxmi.
pfb></texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/txfonts/rtxr.pfb></texlive/201
1/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/txfonts/t1xtt.pfb></texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fon
ts/type1/public/txfonts/txex.pfb></texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/t
xfonts/txsy.pfb></texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/avantgar/uagk8a.pfb><
/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/avantgar/uagko8a.pfb></texlive/2011/te
xmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmb8a.pfb></texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1
/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb></texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmri8a.p
fb>
Output written on ms_0.pdf (21 pages, 16859480 bytes).
Transcript written on ms_0.log.

[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'ms_0.aux' (1473114223 >= 1473114222)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'ms_0.out' (1473114223 >= 1473114222)
[verbose]: now stamping pdf file 'ms_0.pdf' with stamp 'arXiv:submit/1603195 [astro-ph.EP] 5 Sep 2016'
[verbose]: stamped pdf file
[verbose]: PDFTEX paper, check "/opt/teTeX/submissions/1603195/".

[verbose]: All done.

[verbose]: AutoTeX process succeeded
[verbose]: AutoTeX made a pdf.
[verbose]: Moving .../1603195/ms_0.pdf => .../1603195/tex_cache/1603195.pdf

[verbose]: All generated files successfully moved.
[verbose]: ** AutoTeX job completed. **
```

Comment: probably a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320838/natbib-undefined-citations-when-uploading-to-arxiv?rq=1  you need to upload the bbl file generated by bibtex

Comment: I don't understand. One of the files in my source code that I upload is a .bbl file containing all the bibtex entries (for example, @ARTICLE{...}, etc.). What are you saying that I need?

Comment: This is so amazingly frustrating. Trying this for days on end.

Comment: I have avoided this issue by including the citations in the main document. Maybe for the ArXiV this may be the least frustrating method if all else fails.

Comment: how would i do this if all of my references are in the form @ARTICLE{...} and I have 70 of them?

Comment: Natbib and the arxiv don't get along, and even with other citation packages you need to pay attention (e. g. up until earlier this year the arxiv used TeXLive 2011 whose version of the biblatex package was incompatible to that included in later versions of TeXLive). Are you sure you need to include natbib?

Comment: Max, I need to include natbib as it is the style which MNRAS uses for their references layout. The arxiv will not accept my paper in pdf format from sharelatex, as they detect that it has been sourced from Latex. The problem is that their Latex compilers are so terribly out of phase with what other people are using. Is there no hint in the code I put up above of something that may solve this issue?

Comment: According to your errors the arxiv is not finding your citations. Are you uploading the `bbl` file, which contains only LaTeX commands such as `\bibitem`, or are you uploading the `bib` file, which contains the bibtex specifications such as `@ARTICLE{...}`? The `bbl` file is what you should be uploading but your comment above suggests that you may be uploading the `bib` file. Alternatively, as Leucippus suggests, you can comment out the `\bibliography{...}` line from your TeX file and, instead, manually include the `bbl` file -- this is what I always do as means I only need to upload one file.

Comment: No the file that has `@ARTICLE` is the `.bib` file which is the source file for bibtex and not readable by latex.  Latex (and arxiv) need the `.bbl` file which is the _output_ from bibtex, and contains the generated latex-syntax bibliography that is input into your document.

Comment: @Andrew I'm having the same problem as OP.  I have uploaded my bbl file along with the tex file, but it's still telling me my citations are undefined.  It's also telling me the references in my paper that are referencing labeled equation are undefined.  What do you mean by "manually include the bbl file"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To upload a paper on arXiv you have to include the `bbl` file. Sharelaex creates the `bbl` files in the background, but it is not visible in the file panel.  To get a copy of the `bbl` one has to click the "logs and output files" icon beside the "compile/recompile icon", then click the "other logs & files" button and select `bbl`. This will download the file `output.bbl`. You have to change the name to `<main-file>.bbl` where `<main-file>.tex` is the name of the original source file.  Finally, you can upload the `bbl` created in this way to arXiv.

Comment: Thank you Guido, David, and Andrew. I now use the .bbl file instead of the .bib file and it seems to work, though the arXiv is still giving me error messages such as `Package natbib Warning: Citation `marboeuf14' on page 1 undefined on input line
96.' Even with these errors is seems to now produce the references in my document. It would be helpful to know why it is still giving me these messages, but by and large I thank you all very much.

Comment: I'm uploading my .bbl file but it's still giving me this citation undefined error on all of my citations.  It's also giving me an undefined error for any references to labeled equations. :(

Comment: @layman did you figure out a way to solve it?

Comment: @RinW I did, but this was 3+ years ago, so I completely forgot about having this problem, let alone what the solution is.  Hope you can find it!

Comment: I wish this marked solution was edited to address @layman's problem. It is baffling how texlive compiles warning/error-free, yet, arXiv fails.

Answer (score 8):

For me `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` fixed the issue.

Comment: This worked for me !!

Comment: This is so random, but adding `[numbers]` did indeed fix it for me as well.

Comment: Worked for me, too! Thanks, what a random solution.

Comment: didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 2):

Here might be a solution for those of you receiving similar warnings and errors even though you've uploaded a correct bbl file (as comments to the accepted answer suggests).

I got similar errors and warnings, but I've uploaded the correct bbl file as requested by arXiv. However, I was getting a lot of warning messages for references and they all were seemingly related to natbib (in a local compilation I didn't have this issue). In the detail of logs nothing was clear about the actual reason for the main error except that there were many warnings for references.

I was using hyperref package, and since inappropriate order of loading packages sometimes leads to such problems, I've put hyperref and color packages after loading natbib. The problem resolved and arXiv managed to compile it.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add an answer to this thread some 5 years after the accepted answer.

I have encountered exactly the same issue as the OP but submitting the `bbl` and `bib` files didn't solve the arXiv compilation issue for me (i.e. all of the references were still not displayed correctly).

What helped in my case was to also submit the `natbib.sty` file to arXiv, which I located in my MiKTeX directory. The arXiv compiler still threw out some warnings about the references but now all references were correctly displayed in the document.

So if adding the `bbl` and `bib` files does not work for, perhaps try this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, assuming that my main tex file is `main.tex`, I solved this issue by uploading both `main.bbl` and `main.bib` and putting

`\pdfoutput=1`

at the beginning of `main.tex` (see also a similar answer:
[arXiv: Undefined references and citations, unable to convert to PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519573/arxiv-undefined-references-and-citations-unable-to-convert-to-pdf)).

I had Warnings for both citations and other references undefined (citations, equations, tables, etc. undefined), and `\pdfoutput=1` trick would be much useful in this case.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).