# arXiV Tex compilation failing without an error

Tags: arxiv

````
```
[verbose]: Creating arXiv submission AutoTeX object
[verbose]: *** Using TeX Live 2016 ***
[verbose]: Calling arXiv submission AutoTeX process
[verbose]: TeX/AutoTeX.pm: admin_timeout = minion
[verbose]: <state-brier.png>    is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <ns-ts.png>  is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <fml2016-sample.tex> is of type 'PDFLATEX'.
[verbose]: <538-histogram.png>  is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <butterfly.png>  is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <plnolast.png>   is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <mse.png>    is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <aapl-percentiles.png>   is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <sim-student.png>    is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <modellers-ts.png>   is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <pec-hist.png>   is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <pec-histogram.png>  is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <dk-hist.png>    is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <func-be.png>    is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <capm-ts.png>    is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <ev-log.png> is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <nevada.png> is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <overall-cdf.png>    is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <spread-plot.png>    is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <structure.png>  is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <overall-selten.png> is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <ev-brier.png>   is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <quad-ts.png>    is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <densities.png>  is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <aapl-density.png>   is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <overall-brier.png>  is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <dist.png>   is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <plquad.png> is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <profilt-loss.png>   is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <overall-log.png>    is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <option-fit.png> is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <state-log.png>  is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'fml2016-sample.tex'
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hpdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1854743/ && pdflatex 'fml2016-sample.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./fml2016-sample.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2015/03/04 v2.20.2
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-local/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty

This is natbib version 8.31 
*************************************************************
!!WARNING!! !!WARNING!! !!WARNING!! !!WARNING!! 

This version (v8.31) of natbib is stricter in its formatting
requirements for bibitem entries than the previous version
used at arXiv (v7.1).

If your submission encounters a problem see

http://arXiv.org/help/faq/texlive

and the natbib documentation at 

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/

for explanation and adjust your submission accordingly.
The arXiv team.
*************************************************************

) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/times.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latexsym.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbm-macros/bbm.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfig/subfig.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithm.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithmic.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/doublestroke/dsfont.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/appendix/appendix.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg))

Package hyperref Message: Driver: hpdftex.

(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
No file fml2016-sample.aux.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ulasy.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))

Package natbib Warning: Citation `hummel2013fundamental' on page 1 undefined on
input line 118.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `linzer2013dynamic' on page 1 undefined on inp
ut line 118.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `berg2008results' on page 1 undefined on input
line 118.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `silver2016' on page 1 undefined on input line
118.

<ns-ts.png, id=4, 619.56468pt x 203.25937pt> <use ns-ts.png>
Overfull \hbox (109.46542pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 122--123
[] 

LaTeX Warning: `h' float specifier changed to `ht'.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `ns-ts' on page 1 undefined on input line 128.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 130--132

[1{/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 139--140


Package natbib Warning: Citation `ks' on page 2 undefined on input line 144.

[2 <./ns-ts.png>]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 158--159


Package natbib Warning: Citation `savage1971' on page 3 undefined on input line
160.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 176--177


Package natbib Warning: Citation `guo2003' on page 3 undefined on input line 17
8.

(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbm-macros/ubbm.fd)

Package natbib Warning: Citation `b2005' on page 3 undefined on input line 190.


[3]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 203--204


Package natbib Warning: Citation `treynor1961market' on page 4 undefined on inp
ut line 205.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `treynor1962jack' on page 4 undefined on input
line 205.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `sharpe1964capital' on page 4 undefined on inp
ut line 205.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:capm' on page 4 undefined on input line 215.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `data-section' on page 4 undefined on input line 223.

[4]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `capm-ts' on page 5 undefined on input line 237.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `capm-sim' on page 5 undefined on input line 237.

[5]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `nevada-ts' on page 6 undefined on input line 300.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `student-sim' on page 6 undefined on input line 300.

<structure.png, id=61, 778.91pt x 423.5825pt> <use structure.png>
Overfull \hbox (52.55887pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 306--307
[] 

LaTeX Warning: Reference `graph-struc' on page 6 undefined on input line 311.

[6 <./structure.png>]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `savage1971' on page 7 undefined on input line
323.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `shape-fig' on page 7 undefined on input line 331.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 335--336

<pec-histogram.png, id=71, 787.94376pt x 492.84125pt> <use pec-histogram.png>
<538-histogram.png, id=72, 822.07124pt x 492.84125pt> <use 538-histogram.png>
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 351--352


Package natbib Warning: Citation `selten' on page 7 undefined on input line 353
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `rudin' on page 7 undefined on input line 353.


[7] [8 <./pec-histogram.png> <./538-histogram.png>]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 366--367


LaTeX Warning: Reference `dk-hist' on page 9 undefined on input line 368.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `pec-hist' on page 9 undefined on input line 368.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `overall-selten' on page 9 undefined on input line 368
.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `score-comp' on page 9 undefined on input line 380.

[9]
Underfull \vbox (badness 2012) has occurred while \output is active [10]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `mohri12' on page 11 undefined on input line 4
04.

[11]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `albjournal' on page 12 undefined on input lin
e 429.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 452--453
[]\OT1/ptm/m/n/12 Washington
[12]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `silver2016' on page 13 undefined on input lin
e 462.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pasek2015predicting' on page 13 undefined on 
input line 462.

<spread-plot.png, id=115, 780.66656pt x 481.04718pt> <use spread-plot.png>
Overfull \hbox (23.51001pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 477--478
[]\OT1/ptm/m/n/12 FiveThirtyEight (Now/Plus/Polls'

Package natbib Warning: Citation `lott' on page 13 undefined on input line 485.



LaTeX Warning: Reference `overall-brier' on page 13 undefined on input line 489
.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `student-sim' on page 13 undefined on input line 489.

[13 <./spread-plot.png>]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `overall-selten' on page 14 undefined on input line 49
3.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `dk-histogram' on page 14 undefined on input line 493.



LaTeX Warning: Reference `overall-cdf' on page 14 undefined on input line 493.





Package natbib Warning: Citation `linzer2013dynamic' on page 1 undefined on inp
ut line 117.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `berg2008results' on page 1 undefined on input
line 117.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `silver2016' on page 1 undefined on input line
117.

<ns-ts.png, id=1, 619.56468pt x 203.25937pt> <use ns-ts.png>
Overfull \hbox (109.46542pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 121--122
[] 

LaTeX Warning: `h' float specifier changed to `ht'.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `ns-ts' on page 1 undefined on input line 127.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 129--131

[1{/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 138--139


Package natbib Warning: Citation `ks' on page 2 undefined on input line 143.

[2 <./ns-ts.png>]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 157--158


Package natbib Warning: Citation `savage1971' on page 3 undefined on input line
159.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 175--176


Package natbib Warning: Citation `guo2003' on page 3 undefined on input line 17
7.

(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbm-macros/ubbm.fd)

Package natbib Warning: Citation `b2005' on page 3 undefined on input line 189.


[3]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 202--203


Package natbib Warning: Citation `treynor1961market' on page 4 undefined on inp
ut line 204.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `treynor1962jack' on page 4 undefined on input
line 204.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `sharpe1964capital' on page 4 undefined on inp
ut line 204.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:capm' on page 4 undefined on input line 214.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `data-section' on page 4 undefined on input line 222.

[4]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `capm-ts' on page 5 undefined on input line 236.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `capm-sim' on page 5 undefined on input line 236.

[5]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `nevada-ts' on page 6 undefined on input line 299.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `student-sim' on page 6 undefined on input line 299.

<structure.png, id=39, 778.91pt x 423.5825pt> <use structure.png>
Overfull \hbox (52.55887pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 305--306
[] 

LaTeX Warning: Reference `graph-struc' on page 6 undefined on input line 310.

[6 <./structure.png>]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `savage1971' on page 7 undefined on input line
322.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `shape-fig' on page 7 undefined on input line 330.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 334--335

<pec-histogram.png, id=44, 787.94376pt x 492.84125pt> <use pec-histogram.png>
<538-histogram.png, id=45, 822.07124pt x 492.84125pt> <use 538-histogram.png>
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 350--351


Package natbib Warning: Citation `selten' on page 7 undefined on input line 352
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `rudin' on page 7 undefined on input line 352.


[7] [8 <./pec-histogram.png> <./538-histogram.png>]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 365--366


LaTeX Warning: Reference `dk-hist' on page 9 undefined on input line 367.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `pec-hist' on page 9 undefined on input line 367.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `overall-selten' on page 9 undefined on input line 367
.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `score-comp' on page 9 undefined on input line 379.

[9]
Underfull \vbox (badness 2012) has occurred while \output is active [10]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `mohri12' on page 11 undefined on input line 4
03.

[11]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `albjournal' on page 12 undefined on input lin
e 428.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 451--452
[]\OT1/ptm/m/n/12 Washington
[12]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `silver2016' on page 13 undefined on input lin
e 461.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pasek2015predicting' on page 13 undefined on 
input line 461.

<spread-plot.png, id=66, 780.66656pt x 481.04718pt> <use spread-plot.png>
Overfull \hbox (23.51001pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 476--477
[]\OT1/ptm/m/n/12 FiveThirtyEight (Now/Plus/Polls'

Package natbib Warning: Citation `lott' on page 13 undefined on input line 484.



LaTeX Warning: Reference `overall-brier' on page 13 undefined on input line 488
.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `student-sim' on page 13 undefined on input line 488.

[13 <./spread-plot.png>]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `overall-selten' on page 14 undefined on input line 49
2.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `dk-histogram' on page 14 undefined on input line 492.



LaTeX Warning: Reference `overall-cdf' on page 14 undefined on input line 492.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `pl-ts' on page 14 undefined on input line 494.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `pl-nolast' on page 14 undefined on input line 496.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `pl-ts-quad' on page 14 undefined on input line 496.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `mse' on page 14 undefined on input line 496.


Overfull \vbox (1.17552pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[14]
No file fml2016-sample.bbl.
[15]

! LaTeX Error: Command \bfseries invalid in math mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
... 

l.533 From $\citep{guo2003}
$, we know that we can write any proper scoring f...

? 
! Emergency stop.
... 

l.533 From $\citep{guo2003}
$, we know that we can write any proper scoring f...

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on fml2016-sample.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'fml2016-sample.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'fml2016-sample.aux' (1491406296 >= 1491406295)
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running htex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1854743/ && tex 'fml2016-sample.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=tex)
(./fml2016-sample.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[12pt]{amsart}
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
[12pt]{amsart}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on fml2016-sample.log.

[verbose]: tex 'fml2016-sample.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1854743/ && tex 'fml2016-sample.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=tex)
(./fml2016-sample.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[12pt]{amsart}
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
[12pt]{amsart}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on fml2016-sample.log.

[verbose]: tex 'fml2016-sample.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'fml2016-sample.tex'
[error]: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.
*** AutoTeX ABORTING ***
```
````

Comment: Im not really sure what's going on, because the document compiles on Overleaf, ShareLatex etc

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328185/117534 if this helps. Did you upload your bbl file as well?

Comment: I uploaded the `.bib` file.

```
Still getting ! LaTeX Error: Command \bfseries invalid in math mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
... 

l.534 From $\citep{guo2003}
$, we know that we can write any proper scoring f...

? 
! Emergency stop.
... 

l.534 From $\citep{guo2003}
$, we know that we can write any proper scoring f...

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Oh, when I try to upload the .bib file it says There was a problem processing one or more of your files. Please try again.

Comment: Not the `.bib` file. Try uploading the `.bbl` file - that's the one with   all the `\bibitem{...}`. **Not** the `.bib` file - this is the one with all the `@article{...}` etc.

Comment: I did. the `.bbl` file is what I meant. I've also uploaded the `.aux` file. I still get the same error.

Comment: It recognizes 
fml2016-sample.bbl TeX auxiliary Delete
fml2016-sample.tex PDFLATEX Delete

Comment: @troy it seems like not finding the cites is one thing, but it fails at a specific point without an error, which seems to be troubling

Comment: It's a little hard to diagnose... Don't quote me on this, but can you perhaps try uploading a version without `\citep`, or `natbib`, to see if the error is still there?

Comment: I tried that too, ! LaTeX Error: Command \upshape invalid in math mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
... 

l.533 From $\cite{guo2003}
$, we know that we can write any proper scoring fu...

? 
! Emergency stop.

Fails as well. Maybe Ill just kill that line

Comment: Hmm, killing that one specific line made the whole thing compile. I have literally zero idea why, since I have a lot of cites in the paper.

Comment: Can I ask, why the `cite` is in math mode?

Comment: but it *does* report an error: "`! LaTeX Error: Command \bfseries invalid in math mode.`" on line 533.  look for the `!`.