# arXiv: Undefined references and citations, unable to convert to PDF

Tags: arxiv, acmart

I'm unable to get a simple LaTeX file with bibliography (as a `.bbl` file) to be processed through arXiv's TeX submission. I'm using an `acmart` format, which uses `natbib`, and it compiles fine on Overleaf. With arXiv, it warns in the logs that my references and citations are undefined, and at the top of the processing page it says "Unable to convert to pdf".

Here's the example I'm trying to process, in a `main.tex` file:

```latex
\documentclass[acmsmall,nonacm,screen,review,anonymous,10pt]{acmart}
\settopmatter{printfolios=true,printacmref=false}

% This fixes a different, unrelated issue
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\mdseries@tt}{}
\makeatother

\title{This Be The \TeX}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}
This is the introduction, \autoref{sec:intro}. Take a look at \cite{coq}.

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

I also have a `00README.XXX` file with the line `nohypertex` since ACM's loading of `hyperref` clashes with arXiv's.

I have the following bibliography in `biblio.bib`:

```
@misc{coq,
  author       = {The Coq Development Team},
  title        = {The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.9.0},
  month        = jan,
  year         = 2019,
  doi          = {10.5281/zenodo.2554024},
  url          = {https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.2554024}
}
```

Using Submit > arXiv on Overleaf, it gives me the following `main.bbl` in the zip file:

```
%%% -*-BibTeX-*-
%%% Do NOT edit. File created by BibTeX with style
%%% ACM-Reference-Format-Journals [18-Jan-2012].

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

%%% ====================================================================
%%% NOTE TO THE USER: you can override these defaults by providing
%%% customized versions of any of these macros before the \bibliography
%%% command.  Each of them MUST provide its own final punctuation,
%%% except for \shownote{}, \showDOI{}, and \showURL{}.  The latter two
%%% do not use final punctuation, in order to avoid confusing it with
%%% the Web address.
%%%
%%% To suppress output of a particular field, define its macro to expand
%%% to an empty string, or better, \unskip, like this:
%%%
%%% \newcommand{\showDOI}[1]{\unskip}   % LaTeX syntax
%%%
%%% \def \showDOI #1{\unskip}           % plain TeX syntax
%%%
%%% ====================================================================

\ifx \showCODEN    \undefined \def \showCODEN     #1{\unskip}     \fi
\ifx \showDOI      \undefined \def \showDOI       #1{#1}\fi
\ifx \showISBNx    \undefined \def \showISBNx     #1{\unskip}     \fi
\ifx \showISBNxiii \undefined \def \showISBNxiii  #1{\unskip}     \fi
\ifx \showISSN     \undefined \def \showISSN      #1{\unskip}     \fi
\ifx \showLCCN     \undefined \def \showLCCN      #1{\unskip}     \fi
\ifx \shownote     \undefined \def \shownote      #1{#1}          \fi
\ifx \showarticletitle \undefined \def \showarticletitle #1{#1}   \fi
\ifx \showURL      \undefined \def \showURL       {\relax}        \fi
% The following commands are used for tagged output and should be
% invisible to TeX
\providecommand\bibfield[2]{#2}
\providecommand\bibinfo[2]{#2}
\providecommand\natexlab[1]{#1}
\providecommand\showeprint[2][]{arXiv:#2}

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Team}{Team}{2019}]%
        {coq}
\bibfield{author}{\bibinfo{person}{The Coq~Development Team}.}
  \bibinfo{year}{2019}\natexlab{}.
\newblock \bibinfo{title}{The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.9.0}.
\newblock
\newblock
\urldef\tempurl%
\url{https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.2554024}
\showDOI{\tempurl}

\end{thebibliography}
```

And finally, the logs I get from arXiv is [here](https://gist.github.com/ionathanch/c34c18ca5a047b8589b7b52f05221499).

What am I missing here? I don't know if `hyperref` or `natbib` is causing problems, or if it's something else. I'd like to submit my paper in `acmsmall`, so I hope the solution doesn't involve messing with that or other ACM options.

Comment: `arXiv` doesn't process `bib` files, you should upload only the `bbl` file. But the `log` you linked doesn't show any problem: The warnings about undefined references are only in the first run, which is normal.

Answer (score 3):

As the comment says, the warnings are only from the first run, and disappear on subsequent runs. The "Unable to convert to PDF" error was fixed by adding `\pdfoutput=1` to the beginning of the main file.